# Javascript Change Database datetime to HTML input datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-format

I am getting the following datetime from the database

```
2021-09-25T17:04:53.177Z
```

But the Date input required the format in this format.

```
2021-09-22T14:04
```

The Error I get

> The specified value "Sun Oct 17 2021 02:27:28 GMT+0530 (India Standard
> Time)" does not conform to the required format.  The format is
> "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Whats the best way to convert the datetime back and forth to these formats?

Comment: All you need to do is remove the trailing "Z", so `"2021-09-25T17:04:53.177Z".slice(0,-1)`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

how are you doing?
Have you tried splitting the string at that dot?
I would do something like:

```js
const dateTimeFromDatabase = new Date("2021-09-25T17:04:53.177Z").toISOString();
const dateTime = dateTimeFromDatabase.split(".")[0]

document.querySelector("#date-input").value = dateTime;
```

Comment: `new Date("2021-09-25T17:04:53.177Z").toISOString() === "2021-09-25T17:04:53.177Z"`